# Does Netezza support programming i.e. does it have PL/SQL equivalent?

Tags: netezza

Given that netezza has SQL equilalent in Netezza SQL does it support more powerful within-netezza-solutions through some programming model like PL/SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they have what is called NZPLSQL which is based off of postgres' PL/pgSQL.

Comment: Also, You can add your own functions using SQL extension toolkit.